# Hello, I need to add an vector icon in place of marker.snippet in google maps in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

In the below screenshot, I want to place an icon in place of "Read more..." text.

[image: screenshot]

```
override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item: Cluster, markerOptions: MarkerOptions) {
        markerOptions.icon(markerIcon(markerView,item))
                    .title(item.aedList.first().simpleAed.address)
                    .snippet("Read more...")

       if(item.aedList.first().simpleAed.id == "NavMarker"){
           markerOptions.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
           markerOptions.flat(true)
       }
    }
```

is it possible to add one more icon?

Thanks in advance.